# How to install SVN Repository Exploring plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

How to install SVN Repository Exploring plugin for Eclipse? My current Eclipse version is 2.6.1. it does not have SVN Repository Exploring Perspective.

Comment: 2.6.1 ? Any reason for using such an obsolete version ?

Comment: I'm not sure there ever was a 2.6.1 but if there was it is very, very old. Maybe you mean 3.6.1 which is just moderately old.

Comment: My thoughts exactly @greg-449 I did a google search to make sure , and it seems that there isn't any recorded version of the IDE prior to 3.0

Comment: @SaifAsif There was a 2.1 release as I ran it, but I think they went from 2.1 to 3.0

Comment: I see. I was really un-aware of that !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly advise you to update your Eclipse instead of trying to make the plugins work with the obsolete version of the IDE. You will encounter numerous issues in order to make the plugins work with older versions of the IDE since most of the plugins require atleast the 3.4 version of Eclipse to function properly. You will need to dig the archives to find older version of plugins and then some-how make them compatible with the older eclipse

My adivse, download (not update) the latest version of eclipse from the [official website](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). I believe the latest version in use is `4.3.1`.

**Update** : The latest version in use is now 4.4.1 (Luna)

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. i installed latest version and it solve the issue.

Answer (score 10):

Update your [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) firstly.

**Help** --> **Eclipse MarketPlace**, search **subclipse**, click **install**, and then follow the instructions to finish up the installation process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try Help -> Install New Software -> All Available sites

There you can select SVN plugin. try to install

Answer (score 1):

You can add a particular site there, for example 'http://subclipse.tigris.org/' and select the SVN Version as per the Eclipse and trying referring it from 'Help > Install New Software > Add Site' . 
Hope this helps.